# Setting up a remote interpreter in PhpStorm with docker

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

In the Settings of PhpStorm, it is possible to add new interpreters.

`Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP`

I have different docker containers running on my machine (Linux Mint) and I would like to reference each of them as an interpreter.

I tried to follow [the instructions from the doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/configuring-remote-php-interpreters.html) but didn't succeed :(

Should I configure a SSH access trough my docker container or adding my containers as servers? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: Remote PHP Interpreters work via SSH

Comment: Ok, i see how to access my container shell (docker exec -it container_name bash) but not via ssh command with ssh credentials :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LazyOne is right, PHPStorm needs SSH access to work with the container interpreter.

In order to do that you need to [install & configure OpenSSH](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) inside your PHP development image and run its daemon [alongside the PHP-FPM process or Apache](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/).

Then you'll be able to create a remote interpreter via SSH credentials, like so:

[image]
[image]